# Why does memoized function consume so much memory in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I wrote a piece of Haskell code to calculate the length of a [Collatz chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). Given a number n, the next number in the sequence is n/2 if n is even or 3*n+1 if n is odd. The sequence ends when it has converged to 1. I wanted to find the length of the longest chain when starting from any number below some input number.

I tried implementing the length calculation with a memoized function since I expected to need the length of chains starting from some numbers. Thus, the length of the chain starting from 726 would be just 1 + the length of the chain starting from 363, which would already have been calculated. My code is shown below.

```hs
collatz :: Int -> Int
collatz n
    | even n = n `div` 2
    | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

collatzLength :: Int -> Int
collatzLength = (fmap len [0 ..] !!)
    where len 0 = 0
          len 1 = 1
          len n = 1 + (collatzLength . collatz $ n)

maxLengthBelow :: Int -> Int
maxLengthBelow = foldl1 max . fmap collatzLength . enumFromTo 1

main :: IO()
main = print $ maxLengthBelow 10000
```

This code works, but takes a huge amount of memory. When profiling it, running `main` with the input of 10000, `len` is only called 21664 times, as expected, but the program takes 16 seconds and 4.5Gb of memory! What is taking up all that memory? I would have expected the memoized function to produce a fast, low-memory solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the things that makes the Collatz sequence so fun is that there are some small starting seeds that take you way, way out into the atmosphere on their way to 1. In particular, 9663 makes it all the way out to 27114424 before it collapses -- and that's a long memoization list to build!

And, for what it's worth, I expect your memoization list to use three machine words per element: one for the `I#` constructor on the `Int`, one for the contained number, and one for the `(:)` constructor. Let's ask how much space it would take to store 27114424 elements, then:

```
> 27114424 * (64*3) / 1024 {-Kb-} / 1024 {-Mb-} / 1024 {-Gb-}
4.8484368324279785
```

So 4.5Gb sounds about right, perhaps even a little low.

Comment: An oddity: on my machine, this program takes only 2Gb (2.7Gb without optimizations). I wonder why! (It is definitely a 64-bit machine; I can confirm that `Int` can indeed store 2^63-1 faithfully.)

Comment: But shouldn't the lazy evaluation only require the value of the element of collatzLength to be computed when it's value is needed? The highest number may be 27114424, but 27114423 should never be constructed.

Comment: @mentoc3000 Certainly. But you still need to build the spine of the list -- and although you may not need to store both the `I#` and the contained number for elements you don't demand, you'll have to store a thunk saying how to compute that number if it's demanded later, and I doubt that thunk will take less space than the `Int` itself would.

Comment: @mentoc3000 If you use a [trie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-inttrie) instead of a list as your memoization structure, you should see a vast improvement.

Comment: @DanielWagner about your "space oddity".. I don't know much about ghc internals but when an int thunk is evaluated can't the result fit where the thunk used to be?

Comment: @luqui Sure. But the space it uses on my machine is *less* than what it would take to store all the `Int`s and no (presumably larger) thunks!